# Keep the TextField focused (or unfocused) when its key changes

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextField`, and sometimes its `key` must be changed. When the `key` is changed, I observe that the soft keyboard is removed even if it originally was appeared and the TextField was focused.

The problem is, if the TextField was focused, I hope it is still focused after the `key` is changed. How can I do this?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Minimal reproducible code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var textFieldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (_) {
      setState(() => textFieldKey = GlobalKey());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('current textFieldKey=$textFieldKey'),
            TextField(
              key: textFieldKey,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. For me the solution was to not change the key. Of course it might not be possible in your situation, but you could ask yourself if you really need this key to be changed. Think about for what purpose you change this key, and if your application maybe can be refactored in a way so you don't need to change this key anymore. But I as well would love to see any answers that don't require this

Comment: @IvoBeckers thanks for the reply. I really need the keys for some long reasons (long story short: otherwise some subtle bugs).

Comment: @GoldenLion Could you plz elaborate a bit on "background threads" thanks

Comment: if you have the focus on the textformfield the keyboard should appear

Comment: @GoldenLion not true when changing key. You can try the example

Comment: I also chose the solution of not changing the key, instead updating the value via the form or the TextEditingController. It feels like changing the key to show text field updates (whilst keeping the text field focused) is not what Flutter intends to be done, so it is going to be inherently awkward.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final FocusNode _field1Focus = FocusNode();

TextFormField(
                      style: MediumStyle,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      focusNode: _field1Focus,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Field1",
                          labelStyle: MediumBoldStyle),
                      validator: (val) => null,
                      onSaved: (value) => this._field1 = value,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
                        _fieldFocusChange(
                            context, _field1Focus, _field2Focus);
                      },
                    ),

  _fieldFocusChange(
      BuildContext context, FocusNode currentFocus, FocusNode nextFocus) {
    currentFocus.unfocus();
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is, when the *key* changes, how to keep keyboard